# Mutual certificates authentication in SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, ws-security, x509

I have a Jax-ws web service. I've successsfuly tested it with soap ui. but now I've added mutual authentication security. Client and server just exchange with x.509 certificates. How to configure soap ui to have its certificate and validated server's ones. Without any passwords, signatures and encryption. Just certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links:

- [Tryst with Technology 2 (two) way SSL using soapUI as client and
  server](http://ejvyas.blogspot.de/2010/12/2-two-way-ssl-using-soapui-as-client.html)
- [soapUI SSL Settings](http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-soapUI/preferences.html#SSL%20Settings%20Tab)

Comment: This is about mock services, but could I do it for simple services?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like client certificate authentication has been broken in SoapUI since version 4.6.4.  You can modify the source code like this:

*Line 273 of class com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUISSLSocketFactory needs to be changed from*

```
SSLSocket sslSocket = ( SSLSocket )getSocketFactory().createSocket( socket, host, port, autoClose );
```

*to*

```
SSLSocket sslSocket = ( SSLSocket )sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket( socket, host, port, autoClose );
```

Posted on http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=23441